# Jquery DataTable: Sum table rows and columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I want to create a table where **ROW AND COLUMN sums both** are displayed

Footer Callback covers showing running column sums
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

But I would like to have like below Picture a footer row summing the columns and the last column showing row sums and it should work together with row and column filtering

[image]

Could someone please tell me how to do it with JQuery DataTables

Comment: More info needed. Are these number inputs? Or just static number values you want to total? Also, you might get more help stating what you've tried and either showing your attempt or linking to a Plunkr or something with your attempt.

Comment: @Kinglish they are static data not input. I am able to do the column sum and populate bottom row but not Row sum and populate right most row

Comment: can you share the code you've written till now?

Answer (score 2):

To show the sum of row, you'll need to add a new column 'Total' just like in your image. You can show the sum of particular columns in this.

- First add new `<th>Total</th>` in the `thead`
- Then add new column in `columns` while initializing dataTable

  ```
   {
     "targets": 0,
     "data": null,
     "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
              return parseInt(row.column1,10) + parseInt(row.column2,10) + parseInt(row.column3,10);
     }
   }
  ```